# How to limit the number of tabs on a UITabBarController?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I have a working iPhone app with a UITabBarController. It all works fine. The app has more tabs than can be shown across the portrait width of the display, so we see 5 tabs in total (the last being the "more" tab). The thing is, we want to relegate some of the "less interesting" things to be behind the "more" tab. I know that if I had just 2 view controllers, then I'd see just 2 tabs, and so on until I exceeded 5 tabs.

How can we show just 4 tabs (3 plus a "more" tab), instead of 5?

My guess is: this is not possible by just setting an attribute (which would certainly be convenient!), since I cannot find anything in the docs, or here frankly, to suggest otherwise.

Short of implementing my own "more" tab, and supplying the tab bar controller with only 4 view controllers (the last being my own "more" controller), any tips, tricks, or hints are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @blueberryfields and @raidfive. I have learned that if the answer isn't already on SO, there is no answer. :-) Which is why I asked. My "solution" will be a regular UITabBarController with 4 view controllers, the last being my own "More" view controller that implements a table view. Kind of surprising there is no UITabBarController attribute to set the max visible tabs. Oh well. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wanted to wrap this up. In the end, I implemented my own "More" controller, and supplied the UITabBarController with just 4 view controllers, the last being my More controller.

The custom More controller is little more than a generic UITableViewController sub-class that I create when I create the UITabBarController's main tabs and associated controllers. I then add row titles and corresponding UIViewControllers to an array in the More view controller. When that tab is visible and a row is tapped, I just push the appropriate view controller.

The whole effect looks totally "stock", except I have 4 tabs instead of 5. It was less of a hassle than I thought it would be to implement, as well. Always a bonus.

Hope this helps someone down the line.

Comment: Hi I am facing the same problem . Can you describe little more how to handle navigation from other tab bar to more tab with different tab(i.e from 1at tab to 5th tab and then from 1st tab to sixth tab)

Answer (score 3):

This does not appear to be possible with the standard UITabBarController. I also don't think anyone else has run into this problem, and solved it for you already.

Answer (score 2):

You are either going to have to subclass `UITabBarController`, which could get a bit messy, or just write your own tab bar control like you mentioned. There is really no other way around it as @blueberryfields mentioned. Custom tab bars seem pretty common when dealing with this issue, and I suggest going that route if you are really set on only showing 3 tabs at a time.