# Is is possible to add a 5th tab bar button instead of "More" Button?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm working on an iphone application that has exactly 5 tab bar buttons.

I've created a custom tab bar and added 5 buttons to it, each with a separate view controller.

The buttons are showing fine, but the 5th view controller is not loading on 5th tab bar button press. This might be because the 5th button is supposed to be the "More" button. Is their some way to override it?

Comment: you need to create custom tab bar...

Comment: Solved: Just updated my xcode to a new build version...works fine now..Thanks for the answers though

Comment: This SO question might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048359/how-to-limit-the-number-of-tabs-on-a-uitabbarcontroller/5111241#5111241

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize your tab bar to do so.
There're some exist ones, like the one below:
https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/CustomTabBar
It works Excelent! And you'll see the screenshot that it use five tabs. :)

Answer (score 2):

No the more button wil only show if you have more then 5 viewcontroller in the tabbarcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

AS per apple **human interface guidelines** if you have more than 4 tabs last tab is displayed as more tab and **you can not alter it**